# Content update of SDCard

Tags: windows, embedded, usb, sd-card

I'm a developer and I'm developing a product embedded with onboard USB and a SDCard and it works also like a SDCard reader.
The content of SDCard can be modified by PC or by the board's microprocessor.
When the content of SDCard is modified by PC with windows operating system (for example create, delete, move, rename files), the board's microprocessor can view the changes but if the board's microprocessor makes changes to the content of SDCard, the PC doesn't detects the changes.
I tried to refresh the windows that show the files or to develop a custom application but the changes are not seen.
The only way to view the changes is to detach and attach the USB in the USB.

Are there other ways to solve my problem? For example is it possible to set the operating system to refresh the content of SDCard periodically?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like a recipe for disaster to have the embedded device and PC be modifying the file system simultaneously, unless the filesystem is designed for such a thing (And it probably isn't)

Comment: It's not correct: the PC and embedded device does not modify simultaneously the same file system but two file system (PC and embedded device) can access simultaneously in the same SDCard.

In this way can happen that the files are corrupted but the PC and Embedded device write in differents files.

Comment: both the host and the embedded device will be modifying the file system structure (the FAT and directories, for example).  The host will cache some sectors, the embedded device will cache some sectors.  In the end, you risk a corrupted filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use MTP instead of being a mass storage device?

From the wikipedia page on [Media Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol):

> A main reason for using MTP rather than, for example, the USB mass-storage device class (MSC) is that the latter operates at the granularity of a mass storage device block (usually in practice, a FAT block), rather than at the logical file level. In other words, the USB mass storage class is designed to give a host computer undifferentiated access to bulk mass storage, such as compact flash, rather than to a file system, which might be safely shared with the target device (except for specific files which the host might be modifying/accessing). In practice, therefore, when a USB host computer has mounted an MSC partition, it assumes absolute control of the storage, which then may not be safely modified by the device without risk of data corruption until the host computer has severed the connection. Furthermore, because the host computer has full control over the connected storage device, there is a risk that the host computer may corrupt the file system, reformat it to a file system not supported by the USB device, or otherwise modify it in such a way that the USB device cannot completely understand it.

Comment: Thank you Brian.

I too thought to use MTP but maybe the framework that I used for implement the USB protocol, doesn't implement the MTP protocoll. I'll check.

Comment: MTP is exactly what I was thinking when I left my comment above.

Comment: Thank you for replies and sorry for my delay.

I'm asking to implement a MTP protocol but I'm not sure if this will be implement.
Meanwhile, is there a way to force re-enumeration of an USB?